# How to make mongodb aggregate stop if found a document?

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, nosql, aggregate-functions

Long story short, I was using `.exists({ $where: { "this.a > this.b" } })` before locally. Worked as a charm.

Figured aws doesn't support `$where` so I had to use [supported](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/mongo-apis.html) operators.

Using now:

```
.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      diff: {
        "$subtract": [
          "$a",
          "$b",
          
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      diff: {
        $gt: 0
      },
    }
  }
])
```

It contains only supported operators, but it looks ugly, and most importantly it will run through all documents to run the pipeline through. The only thing I want to know if there's a document that matches the criteria. If there is, stop the execution, and it's enough even to return true/false.

Reason being if there are thousands of records, running through all of them, vs if the first one matches just return true immediately makes difference.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: okay it does not stop execution if found document, mongodb have Preferred `$expr` alternative of `$where`.

Comment: Not supported either by aws...

Comment: oh aws is really poor, i don't see any option other than your, or it would be easy if you add one `diff` field and save the difference of both field in collection.

Comment: Putting a `$limit` after the `$match` didn't allow it to stop early?